# Fail to create Virtualenv with jenkins using pipenv

Tags: python, jenkins, virtualenv, pipenv, pyenv-virtualenv

I'm trying to install dependencies using pipenv, my `Jenkinsfile` is as the following

```
pipeline {

   agent any
  
    stages{
        stage('Install dependencies') {
            steps {
                    echo 'Install dependencies'
                    sh 'python3 --version'
                    sh 'pip3 install pipenv==2022.5.2'
                    sh 'pipenv --rm || exit 0'
                    sh 'pipenv install'
            }
        }
```

But I got the following error

> [Pipeline] sh
>
> - pipenv install Creating a virtualenv for this project… Using /usr/bin/python3.8 (3.8.10) to create virtualenv… /usr/bin/python3: No
>   module named pipenv.pew
>
> Virtualenv location:  Traceback (most recent call last):   File
> "/usr/bin/pipenv", line 11, in 
> load_entry_point('pipenv==11.9.0', 'console_scripts', 'pipenv')()   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pipenv/vendor/click/core.py",
> line 722, in **call**
> return self.main(*args, **kwargs)   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pipenv/vendor/click/core.py", line
> 697, in main
> rv = self.invoke(ctx)   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pipenv/vendor/click/core.py", line
> 1066, in invoke
> return _process_result(sub_ctx.command.invoke(sub_ctx))   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pipenv/vendor/click/core.py", line
> 895, in invoke
> return ctx.invoke(self.callback, **ctx.params)   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pipenv/vendor/click/core.py", line
> 535, in invoke
> return callback(*args, **kwargs)   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pipenv/cli.py", line 349, in install
> core.do_install(   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pipenv/core.py", line 1755, in
> do_install
> ensure_project(   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pipenv/core.py", line 616, in
> ensure_project
> '{0}: Your Pipfile requires {1} {2}, ' TypeError: **str** returned non-string (type NoneType)

I'm using `Python 3.8` and I'm running `jenkins` in my local machine (Ubuntu 20.04)

Is it a version issue or maybe I need to add specific jenkins plugins ? Any suggestion please

Answer (score 0):

I used the following commands

```
pipeline {
   agent { label 'python3'}

  
    stages{
        stage('Install dependencies') {
            steps {
                    echo('....Install dependencies & Create VirtualEnvironment ..')
                    sh 'pip3 install --user pipenv'
                    sh 'pipenv --rm || exit 0'
                    sh 'pipenv install --pre --dev'
            }
        }
```

Note: I'm using `python3.9`

My **Pipfile** is as the following

```
[[source]]
url = "https://pypi.org/simple"
verify_ssl = true
name = "pypi"

[packages]
pyspark= "==3.2.1"
boto3= "*"
botocore= "*"

[dev-packages]
pytest=                "==7.1.2"
pytest-spark=          "==0.6.0"
coverage=              "==4.5.3"
pylint=                "==2.13.9"
mypy=                  "==0.960"
pydocstyle=            "==6.1.1"

[requires]
python_version = "3.9"

[pipenv]
allow_prereleases = true
```